# Only one instance being printed when there are many others

Tags: python, python-3.x, praw

When trying to append `comment` to `x`, only one instance of `comment` is being printed despite there being many others.

```
    with open("testingusercomments.txt", "r") as a, open("testingusercommentstmp.txt", "a") as x:
        try:
            for comment in r.redditor("username").comments.new(limit=None):
                if comment not in a.read().split("\n"):
                    print(comment)
                    x.append(comment)
```

Although this code only returns one instance of `comment` the code below returns the proper amount.

```
with open("testingusercomments.txt", "r") as a, open("testingusercommentstmp.txt", "a") as x:
    try:
        for comment in r.redditor("username").comments.new(limit=None):
            if comment not in a.read().split("\n"):
                print(comment)
```

Is there a problem appending to a file while searching for comments? Is there something I've missed to solve this?

Comment: `if comment not in a.read().split("\n")` `a.read()` returns the whole file just the first time. After that the read head is at the end of the file so it returns a blank string. This may not be your issue but is this intended?

Comment: @Primusa, Doesn't `a.read()` return only the first line of a file?

Comment: @Dansey Nope, for that do `a.readline()`. Also, why are you splitting by `'\n'`?

Comment: `a.read()` should eventually include comment and `\n` (after I get `x.append` working)

Comment: Any tips for receiving an answer? Should I add anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I'm unsure of the cause, I've found a solution.

```
x = []
for comment in r.redditor("username").comments.new(limit=None):
    if comment not in x:
        x.append(comment)
```